# Patient-sample mapping in GSE72056 dataset

Tags: rna-seq, read-mapping, cancer

I want to use the single-cell data from the following expression profiling which concerns the RNA-seq of metastatic melanoma:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE72056

The data was also analyzed here,
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4944528/

However I cannot find the mapping between patient and single-cell samples anywhere, neither in the paper nor in the supplementary materials. Anybody has an experience with this data?

Note that in the Supp1 (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4944528/bin/NIHMS791837-supplement-Supp1.doc) from the paper, at Table S1 (almost at the end of the file) that represents the mapping between tumor and patient, which is a one-to-one mapping. But no mapping between samples and tumors found.

Comment: No answer yet?!

Comment: If there is no answer, it is likely because no one has found an answer. Clearly you have had some trouble with this, perhaps it is a difficult question to answer.

Comment: Hey i briefly checked the publication. It is really hard to make a connection between the sequenced sample names and actual sample name. What I usually do is to write to the authors directly..

Comment: OK Thanks. I will go for it.